# Tire seems to ignore page variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, mongoid, tire

I am using Tire and ElasticSearch.  I need to programatically create filters, so I don't want to use the simple search method.  The simple method works just fine:

```
Item.search("blender",:page => 1, :per_page => 1)
```

This returns the first hit, and when you send page = 2, it returns the empty set, which is correct (for this data set).

However, when you use the indirect method:

```
search = Tire::Search::Search.new("items", :page => 2)
search.query { string('name:blender') }
search.results.count
```

This always returns 1, no matter what value you send in for page, you can send 100,000 and it still returns the first item.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer:

```
search = Tire::Search::Search.new("items")
search.from 1   #use from and size for pagination with indirect queries
search.size 1
search.query { string('name:blender') }
search.results.count
```

Hope this helps somebody else.